Adding new realtionship to a node which has other relationship of different types removes the old relationship
I am having issues adding a new relationship to a node with existing relationship,  For example, in the code snippets shown below, If there is a Student with a Course relationship already added, trying to add a Department relationship removes/unsets the existing course from the student.
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Node
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String elementId;
    private String name;
   
    @Relationship(type="TAKES", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Course course;
    
    @Relationship(type="TAKES", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Department dept;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Node
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String elementId;
    private String name;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Node
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String elementId;
    private String name;
}

public interface StudentRepository extends Neo4JRepository<Student, String>{}

public interface CourseRepository extends Neo4JRepository<Course, String>{}

public interface DeptRepository extends Neo4JRepository<Department, String>{}


public class StudentService {
     private StudentRepository studentRepository;
     
 ...
     public void addCourse(String name, Course c) {
          Student s = studentRepository.findByName(name);
          s.setCourse(c)
          studentRepository.save(s);
     }

     public void addDepartment(String name, Department d) {
          Student s = studentRepository.findByName(name);
          s.setDepartment(d);
          studentRepository.save(s);
     }
}



It appears I have to do some thing like below to mitigate this problem.  However, it gets difficult when the Node has many(6, in case) existing relationsips.
public void addDepartment(String name, Department d) {
          Course c = courseRepository.findByName();
          Student s = studentRepository.findByName(name);
          s.setCourse(c)    // Without this, it will remove it from the graph
          s.setDepartment(d);
          studentRepository.save(s);
     }

How can I solve this problem?  Does Neo4J has some mechanisms to mitigate this issue? It gets even harder when there are chain of relationships to be addressed. Thank you.

It depends how you are loading the nodes. Is your findByName in the StudentRepository just a defined method or do you have a custom @Query annotation on this. In the second case, you need to ensure that the Departments get loaded with the Student.

There are some issues with updating dynamic relationships in neo4j spring. There is a thread about it in neo4j community, that mentions issues when the relationship has @GeneratedValue annotation. There was an issue raised on GitHub and changes were merged in a while ago. Don't know if the latest version resolves all the issues.
So, i guess, you can try some different approaches:

Retrieve the record, re-set the existing relationship and also add the new one and then save.
Loading the entity as it is (without all relationships) and persisting it via the Neo4jTemplate#saveAs(entity, YourProjection.class), as proposed in the thread of the link.
Remove the @GeneratedValue annotation.
(Check if the fixes they added in later versions resolve this)

